# How to spread a key-value pair across multiple columns and flatten the matrix based on another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using Pandas 1.2.0, I want to transform this dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'a': ['x_1', 'x_1', 'x_1', 'x_1', 'x_1', 'j_2', 'j_2', 'j_2', 'j_2', ],
'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 5],
'c': [6, 3, 0, 1, 3.4, 4.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.88]})
```

where column 'a' contains the groups, while 'b' and 'c' represent the key and value respectively:

```
     a  b     c
0  x_1  1  6.00
1  x_1  2  3.00
2  x_1  3  0.00
3  x_1  4  1.00
4  x_1  5  3.40
5  j_2  1  4.50
6  j_2  2  0.10
7  j_2  3  0.20
8  j_2  5  0.88
```

into:

```
     a    1    2    3    4     5
0  x_1  6.0  3.0  0.0  1.0  3.40
1  j_2  4.5  0.1  0.2  NaN  0.88
```

My attempt:

```
df.set_index(['b', 'a'], append=True).unstack('b')

         c                     
b        1    2    3    4     5
  a                            
0 x_1  6.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
1 x_1  NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN   NaN
2 x_1  NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN   NaN
3 x_1  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0   NaN
4 x_1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.40
5 j_2  4.5  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
6 j_2  NaN  0.1  NaN  NaN   NaN
7 j_2  NaN  NaN  0.2  NaN   NaN
8 j_2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.88
```

What should I do next to flatten the diagonals of these sub-matrices and group by 'a'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: A typo in the sample data made `pivot` not work because of duplicates. `pivot` should work as well `df = df.pivot(index='a', columns='b', values='c')` or `df = df.pivot('a', 'b', 'c')`:

Tested on your specific version.

```
#pip install pandas==1.2.0
#both pivot and pivot_table should work on this version. However, this code for "pivot" would NOT work on earlier versions of pandas. Not sure the exact version but I think it was fixed in 2019.
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'a': ['x_1', 'x_1', 'x_1', 'x_1', 'x_1', 'j_2', 'j_2', 'j_2', 'j_2', ],
'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 5],
'c': [6, 3, 0, 1, 3.4, 4.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.88]})
df = df.pivot_table(index='a', columns='b', values='c')
df
Out[1]: 
b      1    2    3    4     5
a                            
j_2  4.5  0.1  0.2  NaN  0.88
x_1  6.0  3.0  0.0  1.0  3.40
```

Comment: ``df.pivot("a", "b", "c")``  should be faster. seems your answer has the NaN in column 5 instead of column 4

Comment: @sammywemmy the sample data was changed after I began writing my answer.

Comment: I had to add ".reset_index()" to obtain the desired header.